# PostgreSQL Select every fifteen day of month

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

Hello i have some record:

```
date               Money

1/6/2014            100
12/6/2014            2200
13/6/2014            500
1/3/2014            100
2/5/2014            2200
30/5/2014            500
30/6/2014            100
23/6/2014            2200
31/6/2014            500
```

Well, i have one param, its date for example i need all record of 30 of july but i need the sum of record if very easy that

```
select sum(money) from info where date <= param
group by month
```

But now i need all record group by day of month but i need every fifteen for every month  to lower the parameter in my result i need for example

```
param = 30/6/2014
```

The result I hope to get:

```
15/6/2014   sum(money)
15/5/2014   sum(money)
15/4/2014   sum(money)
```

I need the record for every fifteen of month

Comment: So basically you want to sum by "fiscal month", where the 15th is your cutover? so your `15/6/2014` would actually cover dates `16/5/2014 -> 15/6/2014`?

Comment: Yes but not how to do it

Comment: I think your question is quite hard to understand. So what you want is, for `15/4/2014` -> sum all the record having `any/4/2014` is it true?

Answer (score 1):

The question is how to arrange it to days up to the 15th are in one month and days from the 16th onward are in the next month.  You can do this by subtracting 15 days.  This puts all days from 1-15 in the previous month.  Then, add a month.  Here is an approach in Postgres:

```
select to_char(date - 15 * interval '1 day' + interval '1 month', 'YYYY-MM') as mon,
       sum(money)
from info
where date <= param
group by to_char(date - 15 * interval '1 day' + interval '1 month', 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want month-to-the-15th, then you can do:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as mon,
       sum(money)
from info
where extract(day from date) <= param
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1;
```

Or, if it is only for one month:

```
select sum(money)
from info
where to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(param, 'YYYY-MM') and
      date <= param;
```

Comment: Gordon thanks, but in the query I see that you take all my data under parameter least 15 days (30/6/2014 - 15 days for month), but what if me to enter the date 15/06/2014 in this case should not subtract 15 days right?, 
My question is whether to make the sum is necessary to subtract the select but not in the where? I see that the result of the query always takes the lower results in equal 30 for month 6, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alberto . . . I don't understand the comment.  Perhaps you can show what you mean by editing the question and adding sample data with the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, In the sql query results always taking under the date 30/6/2014, the only thing in the query has a field called mon has the correct date for each 15 month, but where the query always takes the sum of the amounts the date 30, 29, 28 ... 15/6/2014 my question is how should condition the query to only add the the date less than or equal to the 15th of each month, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help, but i need select for all day group and select record to for "fiscal month"  in this case every 15th, i need group my record for example: 15/6/2014   sum(money) for next row of the record: 15/5/2014   sum(money) and for next row of the record: 15/4/2014   sum(money) , i need select data from table where data for every month 15th, (fiscal month)

Comment: @Alberto . . . That is what my original answer did.